# how to replace a character by its ascii in SQL SELECT statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ascii

The database we are using which we only have reading access has a character that is shown as a square, it has the ascii code of 26 or x1A in hex and i want to replace it in the SELECT statement to another character using its ascii only.

We are using Oracle 10g.

Is there a way? Maybe using Regular Expressions?

Thank you,,,

Comment: In all encodings I know, the code 26 is a control character. There's no replacement for it. The best idea is probably to delete it.

Comment: the database was copied from DB2 to Oracle, so this 26 Ascii control character was a normal character in the EBCDIC encoding in DB2 which couldn't be represented by Ascii

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use use the `REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(text,CHR(26),otherChar) FROM .........
```

Comment: i want the character which appears as a square that has the Ascii of (26) to replaced by another character i want, for example:

SELECT Replace(columnName, 'here the square character', 'any other character') FROM Table

when i exported the table to MS Excel i could replace the square character by the function:
=SUBSTITUTE(D5;CHAR(26);"R")

Comment: Should be `CHR(26)`, not `CHAR`.